# MySQL : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I got error :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

This is my Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `swat` (`Category`, `Importance_JK`, `MaxStrength`, `Person_id`, `SWAT_id`, `Strength`, `cost`, `date_Complete`, `due_Date`, `storage_id`, `updated`, `user_FK`) 
    VALUES ('1','2','we1','546','46','we','500','2016-04-19','2016-04-18','','2016-04-18','37')
```

If i print this query in SQL, then this MySql error occurs:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sidemoin_crucialstuff`.`swat`, CONSTRAINT `swat_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Person_id`) REFERENCES `key_people` (`Key_Person_ID`))

Any help please?

Comment: Show your ddl please

Comment: [ALTER TABLE `swat`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `swat_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Importance_JK`) REFERENCES `tbl_importance` (`I_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `swat_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_FK`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`user_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `swat_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Person_id`) REFERENCES `key_people` (`Key_Person_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `swat_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`Category`) REFERENCES `swat_category` (`sc_ID`);
]

Comment: Do not add it as a comment. Add it to your question using the edit function

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your foreign key value is not getting inserted.So you can do one thing please specify the null value in database at the FK column and then try to run the query and check

Comment: Thnx for answer @aarju mishra, but i have already set it NULL in DB at the FK column

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because Foreign key constraints.

You've added a reference on `Person_id` from `key_people` table. Now what every value you're adding in `Person_id` field must be present in `key_people` table. Because you're `referencing` the value from table table.

So before inserting any values to `swat` table make sure you've required values inserted in referencing tables. Otherwise it will keep throwing you foreign key constraint errors.

What you can also do is first check if the value is present in referencing tables, if not add a NULL value into the corresponding columns.

> Note: For above solution you must have to allow NULL values in those
>   referencing columns plus this won't be a perfect solution if you're
>   planning to fetch the data based on foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference b/w Person_id with Key_People.

This is called parent child relationship.

The value must be there in Parent table before inserting in Child table.
So accordingly you have to insert the value in parent table before inserting in Swat :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially find which row of data in the Child table is incorrect by executing the below query

```
SELECT childTable.id, childTable.fid, parentTable.id 
FROM childTable
LEFT JOIN parentTable
  ON parentTable.id = childTable.fid
WHERE childTable.fid IS NOT NULL and parentTable.id is NULL
```