# C# - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I know that there are plenty of questions regarding this issue but I have not been able to solve it.
I am doing a graphic interface to add/remove employee and manage absences.

I have been reading and testing those advices [stackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686545/mysql-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) but I cannot change the database as it is already given by our professor.

The value from the foreign key is already in the table "service" that I called "department" on the code.

I have the following database (for the table on which I get issue):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personnel;
CREATE TABLE personnel (
  IDPERSONNEL int NOT NULL,
  IDSERVICE int NOT NULL,
  NOM varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRENOM varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  TEL varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  MAIL varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS service;
CREATE TABLE service (
  IDSERVICE int NOT NULL,
  NOM varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In the application, that you can see [here](https://github.com/MathieuAscain/Mediatek86) and on the picture just below, I have to modify an employee data and to save it again to the dataGridView.

I have an issue once I click on save. I have an error on my request but I don't know how to solve it.
**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gestionpersonnel`.`personnel`, CONSTRAINT `personnel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`IDSERVICE`) REFERENCES `service` (`IDSERVICE`))**

Here is the method I have been using in the class AccessDataBase:

```
  public static void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            string req = "update personnel set nom = @nom, prenom = @prenom, tel = @tel, mail = @mail, idservice = @idservice ";
            req += "where idpersonnel = @idpersonnel;";
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"@idpersonnel", employee.IdEmployee },
                {"@idservice", employee.IdDepartment },
                {"@nom", employee.FamilyName },
                {"@prenom", employee.FirstName },
                {"@tel", employee.Phone },
                {"@mail", employee.Mail }
            };
            ConnexionDataBase connexion = ConnexionDataBase.GetInstance(connexionString);
            connexion.ReqUpdate(req, parameters);
        }
```

Update 1 :

[image]
I have been following the same order between the database and the code in C# for the request in the string variable.

[image: Screen shot of the application]

Update 2 (reply to @Sharath N S), by using the step by step, I can get a value from the department
[image]

Update 3 (reply to @Crowcoder) : indeed that is the same comment @Sharath N S gave me. I have the feeling that I get the field of the department and not the idDepartment.

Here my code for the save button :

```
 private void BtnSaveEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFamilyName.Text) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPhone.Text) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxMail.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All the informations shall be filled", "Information");
            }
            else
            
            {
                Department department = (Department)bindingSourceDepartments.List[bindingSourceDepartments.Position];
                int idEmployee = 0;
                if (modificationOngoing)
                {
                    idEmployee = (int)dataGridViewEmployee.SelectedRows[0].Cells["idEmployee"].Value;
                }
                Employee employee = new Employee(idEmployee,
                                                 textBoxFamilyName.Text,
                                                 textBoxFirstName.Text,
                                                 textBoxPhone.Text,
                                                 textBoxMail.Text,
                                                 department.IdDepartment,
                                                 department.DepartmentName);

                if (modificationOngoing)
                {
                    controlMyApp.UpdateEmployee(employee);
                    modificationOngoing = false;
                    grpBoxEmployee.Enabled = true;
                    lblShowButtonClicked.Text = "Adding";
                }
                else
                {
                    controlMyApp.AddEmployee(employee);
                }
                FillEmployeesList();
                EmptyEmployeeSelection();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Mysql parameters are positional, not named. Try putting them in the same order as they are in the SQL statement. Though, I can't see the implementation of the code that runs the query so I can't be sure that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Crowcoder. I have updated my message with the picture of phpMyAdmin for this table. In my request I have been following the same order for the name of the columns.

Comment: Indeed you are right @Crowcoder idservice was not in the same order but that still doesn't work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work are you saying it is the same problem? Also, when you debug, what is the value of `employee.IdDepartment` and does that id exist in the service table?

Comment: You don't want the selected index of the combobox, it almost certainly will not match the real id of the record. You want the value of the selected item.

Comment: Sorry regarding your last comment, which line is causing the issue ? Is it Department department = (Department)bindingSourceDepartments.List[bindingSourceDepartments.Position]; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231509/discussion-between-mathieu-seligmann-and-crowcoder).

Answer (score 2):

Please check the value of IDservice that was being sent while updating the Employee details. From the error it looks like the IdService value that is being updated is not present in the parent table service.

Comment: hello @sharanth N S, I can get a value but indeed I have the field of the department name while I should get the idDepartment number

Comment: I do not find the issue